# Windows 11 Update - disable invalid entries

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

All of a sudden, a number of invalid entries has shown up in my Windows update screen with an `Install error - 0x80070103` - see screenshot:

[image]

I tried clicking the proper buttons, but they still give install error. None of them were there before, so I'm pretty sure I'm not missing anything.

How can I disable those entries and make them go away?

Comment: Try [Microsoft's advice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/additional-resources-for-windows-update).

Answer (score 0):

Under `Settings > System > Troubleshoot > Other troubleshooters`, there is a Windows Update troubleshooter.

[image]

Running this troubleshooter **did not** help - it got stuck for several minutes, after which I pressed `Cancel`.

What did help was resetting the Windows Update service by running the following from an Admin command prompt:

```
net stop wuauserv
rd /s /q %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution
net start wuauserv
```

At first glance, it seemed the error was still there.

Then I pressed `Download & install all`, which still gave an error.

But then the top button got renamed to `Check for updates`, and after refreshing updates, all the invalid updates disappeared.

[image]